# Recombine regex match groups into new string using grep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Let's say I have a file `file.txt` with the following content:

```
somelogoutput
INFO: 1549 ducks: 1544 children playing, 5 something-else.
morelogoutput
```

and the following regex that matches the middle line in the file above:

```
grep -P "(\d*) ducks: (\d*) children playing, (\d*) something-else" file.txt
```

**How can I create a formatted string with the match groups?**

ex: "(match group2)/(match group1)"

ex: "1544/1549"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `grep` for this, but you can use `awk`:

```
awk '/^INFO:/{printf "%s/%s\n", $4, $2}' file.txt
```

While I would recommend `awk` for the task as you described it in the question, recombining a string based on regex groups is a task for `sed`:

```
sed -rn 's/INFO: ([[:digit:]]*) ducks: ([[:digit:]]*) children.*/\2\/\1/p' file.txt
```